# Assigning finite values to infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

From my limited exposure to the study of series in the context of elementary analysis books I've gathered that when a series diverges we kick it to the curb. Allegedly Euler and Ramanujan (and presumably other big names) have looked into assigning some sort of finite value to divergent series. Is this something that is standard practise within the more advanced mathematical community and if it is what  information do these assigned values yield about the nature of a given divergent series?

Comment: Some important series diverge , but give good approximations when truncated at some point. The most common example is Stirlings approximation of the factorial.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please? As for as I know Stirlings approximation isn't conventially expressed as a series.

Comment: In Wikipedia you find a series which approximates the factorial even better. If we truncate the $\frac{1}{x}$-term, we get the approximation which is probably more common and which is very good already.

Comment: The topic you are discussing is mostly related to Zeta function Regularization

Comment: Binomial expansion!$$(x+y)^n=x^n+nx^{n-1}y+\dots+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k)}{k!}x^{n-k}y^k+\dots$$Try $x=y=1$ and $n=-1,-2$.

Comment: @vidyarthi analytic continuation then becomes important.

Comment: @SimpleArt since the OP talked about Euler and Ramanujan, I spontaneously gave the comment

Comment: @vidyarthi Good that you know your history  :D

Comment: @SimpleArt sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @vidyarthi not all of us mathematicians remember the history side of the math.  Merely a compliment.